# key is not equal when map in future

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using flutter webview plugin.

`getCookies()` will return a `Future<Map<String, String>>`.

the `containsKey` function is false even "id" exist in the `Map`.

I have no problem if the `Map` does not come from `Future`.

How can I access the value from `Map`?

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.getCookies().then((Map<String, String> _) {
    if (_.containsKey("id")) {
      print(${_["id"]});
    }
 });
```

print map by

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.getCookies().then((Map<String, String> _) {
  print(_);
}
```

output of map values

```
{"locale: en,  tcurrency: 6, id: 10702776, pbe: "}
```

I fix the cookie by this now

```
_flutterWebviewPlugin.getCookies().then((Map<String, String> cookies) {
    Map<String, String> trimCookies = {};
    for (String key in cookies.keys) {
      trimCookies[key.replaceAll("\"", "").trim()] = cookies[key].replaceAll("\"", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure your map contains "id" key? could you print your map before the if condition ?

Comment: Yes, I can get the value if I use the key from _.keys directly.

Comment: could you print the values from _  ?

Comment: Yes, I can print the value and access the value if use the key from _.keys. but _["id"] is null.

Comment: print the _ values and put in your question, I would like to see how the map is

Comment: just update the question

Comment: Just `print(_);` would do. Btw, the convention is to use `_` as parameter name for unused parameters. If you actually use the passed value, you should give it a proper name.

Comment: ok, update again

Comment: `void main() {
  print({'locale': 'en', 'tcurrency': 6, 'id': 10702776, 'pbe': ''});
}` prints `{locale: en, tcurrency: 6, id: 10702776, pbe: }` for me. Where do the quotes come from in the output you added?

Comment: I print the map from the getCookies directly. I have not added quotes.

Comment: Out of ideas. Ensure you tried `flutter clean` (in a terminal window in your project directory)

Comment: The output remains the same after flutter clean. The map only can access by the key from _.keys.

Comment: In the code in the example, `${_["id"]}` should probably be in a string literal. Try the following: `print(map.keys.join("---"));`, and maybe also `print(map.values.join("---"));` and `print(map.entries.join("---"));`, to see what the actual keys and values are. The quotes in the output suggests that something is not as it appears. The extra space before "tcurrency" is also suggesting that something here is part of a string. It's quite possible that you have a map like `{"\"locale: en,  tcurrency: 6, id": "10702775, pbe: \""}`

Comment: I find the key become "key1--- key2--- key3, value become value1---value2---value3---"